# android app engine java: authenticating users

Tags: android, google-app-engine, authentication

I am writing an android application which allows several users
to store their data in the cloud using app engine and need the
application to authenticate these users so that they cannot see
each other's cloud data. It seems that instead of writing my own
authentication protocol it would be better to use google accounts
especially since each user will already have one on android. This
page explains what ClientLogin is (not sure what an installed
application is but presumably it's a desktop application rather than
a web application):

http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps.html

However it appears to me that I don't need to use this mechanism as
android AccountsManager besides storing your usernames and passwords
also stores auth tokens and authrizes the login procedure so the user
doesn't even have to worry about what that procedure is (OAuth 2 or
OpenID or what not).

I have found the following example but don't understand why there is
no intent-filter: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/index.html

The AndroidManifest.xml says:

```
        <!--
            No intent-filter here! This activity is only ever launched by
            someone who explicitly knows the class name
        -->
```

even if I add an intent filter I don't know how to proceed. How can I launch
the activity just knowing the class name anyways?

Can someone please show me exactly how to code the authentication and
persistence of authentication through a token sent with each request to
the app engine server, using AccountsManager? I am looking for a bare bones
set of lines of code. I know that I can then use the app engine Users API to
detect the user logged in, but I need to authenticate first from AccountsManager.

Thanks for your help,

John Goche

Answer (score 1):

I remember on Google IO this was in examples

link to Brad Abrams post:

http://bradabrams.com/2011/05/google-io-session-overview-android-app-engine-a-developers-dream-combination/

includes  "complete source code for the demo:" https://code.google.com/p/cloud-tasks-io

Comment: Yes I am aware of that site from Google IO. The base code for that project is available from eclipse. But I still find it confusing. I need to authenticate my users and send XML instead of JSON over the HTTP link between the android client and the server but am not sure how to go about doing that. Maybe I can have a look at AddTaskActivity.java in the client code and see what I can figure out. Thanks.